# Body Background Image That Doesn't Move Horizontally When The Browser Window Is Shrunk Horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want to position a circular background image / circular image so that it appears as per the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d0qhppvw/

However I do not want to use the

```
<div id="outer-container">
```

that is currently being used.

Then, when the browser is horizontally shrunk just smaller then the width of the div

```
<div id="container">
```

the scrollbar should then be introduced and scrolling all the way over to the right will mean that only half of that image is currently seen.

The other half outside of the container can only be seen if the browser window is expanded horizontally again.

I would ideally like to just add a background image to the body but I'm not sure if it's possible to do this and give it a position that is relative to the container so that regardless of how wide the browser window is, it remains in exactly the same position.

I had also considered adding an absolutely positioned div within the header as per the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nfa8q40s/1/

However the problem with this is that as the browser window is shrunk horizontally and the horizontal scrollbar is introduced, if you scroll to the right, the newly added div adds to the scrollable width of the page.

I want the scrolling to stop at the edge of the container so that just half of the circle is shown.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: as far as I understand it you want something like this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp (look at their example)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately this means the background also remains fixed when scrolling vertically down the page.  I do not want this to happen. My concern is horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with JavaScript:

```js
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  $('#image').css('left', $(this).scrollLeft() +'px');
});
```

```css
#image {
    background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_firefox.gif');
   position:absolute;
   width:60px;
   height:60px;
   z-index:-1;
   background-attachment: scroll;
   background-position: 20px 20px; 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 
#container {
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    background:transparent
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=container>
    <div id=image></div>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```